# does a method implementing a callBack (onSuccess()) return the value returned by onSucess()?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, callback

I override method `getView()` and I'm trying to get the view inflated inside a `onSuccess()` method that return the new view. The value returned by `onSuccess` is it returned by `getView()`?

Here is my code :

```
    @Override 
    public View getView(final int position, final View view,final ViewGroup parent) {

     aMethodWithAcallBack(new myCallBack(){

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Content> contents) {

            contentsList = contents ;
            View mView = inflateIfRequired(view, position, parent);

            if(getItem(position).content_type_id == 2) {
                 bindCard(view, getItem(position));
            }
           else {
              if(getItem(position).content_type_id == 3)
                 bindVideo(view,getItem(position)) ;
           }

           return mView ;
      });


      @override
      public void onFail() {
        //
      }

      return view ;
   }
```

You may be wondering why I used a `CallBack`, I have to use it because the contentsList items are the items of my `ListView`, and this contentsList is initiated thanks to a `callBack` because it's elements are fetched from a server.

Comment: You should revise your architecture. You should do as little as possible in `getView()` and if your `aMethodWithAcallBack()` is asynchronous, you won't get any result you're expecting. Prepare the data before displaying it or implement updates completely synchronously.

Comment: Seems quite strange that `public void onSuccess` can return `mView`. Does it compile?

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I cannot do things synchronosly the contentsList is filled with elements from a server

Comment: @jaibatrik I didn't try it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it cannot be done by returning the value from onSuccess(). Since there would be no main thread to receive the value returned by onSuccess() method.

Explanation:

1) getView() method is invoked from other place - This is one thread let us keep it as main.

2) In the flow of execution of this main thread an async callback method aMethodWithAcallBack() is executed, this async callback call will be a different thread.

3) Main thread which is executing the getView() method will pass thru and exit the method by executing `return view ;`

4) Once async callback is success, the line `return mView ;` will be executed but there is no main thread to receive it. ie we would not have the main thread which had invoked the getView() method.

Comment: your explanation is very clear, thank you very much :)